# Getting status code 400 Bad Request when making HTTP request to shopify

Tags: apex, http

I'm relatively new to SF/APEX, but a developer of 15 years so I'm pretty well versed in making a HTTP request.  For whatever reason, I can't accomplish this using APEX.  When I try to make a simple HTTP request to the Shopify API from the developer console utilizing a class I wrote, I continually get a 400 response that the request is bad.  If I copy the generated URL into the console and CURL it, I get a response just fine.  The URL I am hitting is authorized in my remote site settings as well.  Code below:

```
  Http http= new Http();
  HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
  HttpResponse response;
  Blob headerValue;
  String authorizationHeader = '';
  String url = 'https://myKey:myPW@' + shopify_url +
                   '/admin/api/2020-04/orders.json' +
                   '?updated_at_min=' + system.now().addminutes(-60) +
                   '&updated_at_max=' + system.now() +
                   '&status=any&limit=250';

  request.setEndpoint(url);
  request.setMethod('GET');
  request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  //headerValue = Blob.valueOf(shopify_key + ':' + shopify_password);
  //authorizationHeader = 'Basic ' + EncodingUtil.base64Encode(headerValue);
  //request.setHeader('Authorization', authorizationHeader);
  request.setTimeout(60000);    // if running test json is set from test case

  response = http.send(request);
```

As you can see, I was initially trying to use an authorization header, which did not work, so I tried a more direct method of just dropping the key/pw into the URL string (as suggested by the Shopify API) to no avail.

Would really appreciate some help here, as this is beyond befuddling.  If anyone has any recommendations on how I could have debugged this better too, I would appreciate it as I'm new to SF and all.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Shopify API, but could the caller be the issue? Requests from Salesforce will be coming from a different IP address than your own and there could be some sort of filtering in place on Shopify's side. That's the only thing that comes to mind if the generated URL works perfectly fine copy & pasting from a debug log, but that would probably result in a different error than a 400.

Comment: @nbrown2 yea unlikely.  As mentioned, I tried just curling from my local machine and it works fine, and I've never whitelisted my local machine or anything like that :\

Comment: One other thing that comes to mind is that Salesforce includes some of its own HTTP headers with outbound requests. I find it unlikely, but one of these could be an issue. Just trying to find every possible variable.

Comment: @nbrown Do you know what other headers they include?

Comment: No, unfortunately, I am not finding them documented on Salesforce but a screenshot of a request is in this blog post: https://medium.com/@krissparks/postman-a-salesforce-rest-web-service-28edc0a69851. It's something I noticed years ago when consuming requests from Salesforce in an integration. We used ngrok to capture the outbound requests from Salesforce to debug an issue. The headers aren't too out of the ordinary, things like Vary, Cache-Control, Content-Encoding, etc.